# stack columns values from same dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to know if it's possible to stack columns values from the same data frame with almost the same name.
I have the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'text':['hello','hi'],
        'a':[1,2,],
        'b':[2,1,],
        'a.1':[3,4],
        'b.1':[4,3]
        }
```

I have multiple a. and b. so it goes to a.N and b.N but the end result has to be like the below data frame.

```
data2 ={'text':['hello','hi','hello','hi'],'identifier':[0,0,1,1],
        'a':[1,2,3,4],
        'b':[2,1,4,3],
        }
```

the identifier column is just to know how it was stacked for instance the first 2 values 0,0 came from the original column and 1,1  came from a.1 and b.1.
I hope it all makes sense.

Comment: Are you manipulating dataframes or dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to `pd.wide_to_long` except that you don't have the prefix for the first set.

Try with a custom rename function, then unstack:

```
def rename_col(x):
    out = x.split('.')
    return (x,'0') if len(out)==1 else tuple(out)

df = df.set_index('text')
df.columns=df.columns.map(rename_col)

df.stack(level=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    text level_1  a  b
0  hello       0  1  2
1  hello       1  3  4
2     hi       0  2  1
3     hi       1  4  3
```

---

**Update** Or you can use `pd.wide_to_long` with another rename function:

```
def rename_col(x): return x if x=='text' or '.' in x else x+'.0'

pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=rename_col),
                i='text', j='identifier',
                stubnames=['a','b'],
                sep='.'
               )
```

Output:

```
                  a  b
text  identifier      
hello 0           1  2
hi    0           2  1
hello 1           3  4
hi    1           4  3
```

Comment: Hello! the first option worked flawlessly about the second option I had the error stubname can't be identical to a column name but thank you it worked as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can create the identifier , however here is a way with `groupby` on `axis=1`

```
u = df.set_index("text")
out = pd.concat([g.stack().droplevel(-1) for _,g in 
                 u.groupby(u.columns.str.split('.').str[0],axis=1)],axis=1,keys=u)
```

---

```
print(out)

       a  b
text       
hello  1  2
hello  3  4
hi     2  1
hi     4  3
```